# react navigation how to go back to different stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
});

const CarStack = createStackNavigator({
    Booking: BookingScreen,
    Confirm: ConfirmScreen

});

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack,
    CarStack,
});

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    goTo(){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Confirm')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={css.container}>
                <button onPress={this.goTo.bind(this)}>go to</button>
            </View>
        );
    }   
}



export default class ConfirmScreen extends React.Component {
    goBack(){
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={css.container}>
                <button onPress={this.goBack.bind(this)}>goback</button>
            </View>
        );
    }   
}
```

In home screen, when I click goto, it take me to confirmscreen, which is good.
But when I press go back, it takes me to booking screen instead of home screen. Which is bad.
It suppose to take me to home screen. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define 2 separate navigators and check user/guest in another component. like this:

**Provider.js:**

```
export default class Provider extends Component {
    render() {
        let {key, signedIn, checkedSignIn} = this.state
        return(
            <View>
                {
                    checkedSignIn
                        ? signedIn
                            ? <App />
                            : <SignedOut />
                        : null
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js:**

```
export default createStackNavigator({
    home: Home // sample
})
```

**SignedOut.js:**

```
export default createStackNavigator({
    auth: Auth // sample
})
```

Comment: is this about navigation.goBack() ?

Comment: Yes. after this, navigation.goBack() doesn't take you to Confirm screen because there are two stack navigators and after login (confirm), users should not have access to confirm screen (or auth navigator). try it. please mark the answer, if it worked.

Comment: not working, first of all i'm not doing any auth. Secondly, I got three screen in two stacks. yours are two screen in two stack.

Comment: It's just an example bro. you can add any screens to these stacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-navigation` v2.x or greater, directly use the `navigate` method to go to your `Home` screen.

Customize the back button behaviour and call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')` on the back button press in `Confirmation` screen. This will cause the desired effect.

Since `react-navigation` v2.0, the `navigate` action is less pushy. If the route you specify is already in the stack, then that screen will be opened, instead of pushing a new screen in stack by default.

[Reference](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#navigateroutename-in-stacknavigator-is-less-pushy)

Comment: I just want to go back, not go to a specific screen.

Comment: Problem here is that you are routing to `CarStack` from your `HomeStack`. Navigating from `Home` to `Confirm` mounts the whole `CarStack` on top, which has the initialScreen as `Booking`. Just add a flag when navigating from `Home` to `Confirm` and using that flag you can to check and navigate to the desired previous screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.props.navigtion.goBack('Home')
```

I hope it help you.